# Question about transformation matrix for spin 1 particle

Tags: quantum-spin, coordinate-systems, linear-algebra

For spin one system the bases transformation of $y$ axis:

$|1>_y=\frac{1}{2}|1>+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0>-\frac{1}{2}|-1>$

$|0>_y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1>+0|0>+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|-1>$

$|-1>_y=\frac{1}{2}|1>-i\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}|0>-\frac{1}{2}|-1>$

Put it into matrix
$T=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}& i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& -\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& 0 &\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{2}& -i\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}& -\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$

Where I understood as for a spin $\psi$ evaluated at $z,|\psi>_z$,
it took it into spin evaluated at $y$: $|\psi>_y=T|\psi>$. Thus from linear algebra, $T^{-1}|\psi>_y=|\psi>_z$.

However, the correct answer was to take the transpose of $T$, meaning: $transpose(T)|\psi>_y=|\psi>_z$.

What was wrong with the inverse $T^{-1}$?

*Notice the $transpose(T)$ here was simply the transpose of $T$ and did not take the complex conjugate.($transpose(T)\neq T^{-1}$)

Comment: It seems like this is something that you could check directly. Your notation confuses me a bit but I think you might not have built $T$ properly. Just check it.

Comment: @CosmasZachos thank you very much. I just figured out which part I got it wrong. I misunderstood the notation and $transpose(T)$ was the correct coordinate matrix.

Comment: @secavara you were right, thank you for your help.

Comment: @secavara Indeed, his *T*  is the expected rotation by π/2 around the *x*-axis, as it should be, *but also* multiplied by an extra diag( 1,-i,1) on the right. It is thus unitary, improbably, and merely rephases  the $J_z=0$ state, I think....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|unit>_y=T|unit>$[Each (unit) $y$ component equal to how many $z$ component ]

$transpose(T)|\psi>_y$[Each $\psi_y$ component equal to how many $|\psi>$ of $z$ component]$=|\psi>$

$|unit>=T^{-1}|unit>_y$

$transpose(T)^{-1}|\psi>=transpose(T^{-1})|\psi>=|\psi>_y$

Quote from linear algebra:

Transformation $P_{A\rightarrow B}$ took $V_A$ to $V_B$ was written such that $P_{A\rightarrow B}=[[u1_A]_B,[u2_A]_B…]$ where $[ui_A]B$ was the unit base in $A$ written with respect to unit base in $B$.

In this case, $transpose(T)$ was the corresponding  matrix $P_{|\psi>_y\rightarrow|\psi>}$ transform vector from $|\psi>_y$ base to $|\psi>$ base.

The really confusing part was that: $T$ DID NOT mean it take the unit vector $|\psi>$ and transform it into $|\psi>_y$, instead it specified the component of unit vector in $|\psi>_y$ written in $|\psi>$,  which was very misleading.

The $transpose(T)$ thus transform vector written in $|\psi>_y $ into vector written in $|\psi>$ base. And the rest following directly with the linear algebra.